# Type Mismatches with Modelling Hearthstone

Tags: haskell, types

I have the following code (which is supposed to model the game of Hearthstone).

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.List

type Attack = Int
type HP = Int
type Name = String
type Minion = (Name,Attack,HP) 

type Board = ([Minion],[Minion])

attackMM :: Name -> Name -> Board -> Board
attackMM n m b = do {m1 <- findMinion1 n b;
                     m2 <- findMinion2 m b;
                     m1'<- fst (damageMM (Just m1) (Just m2));
                     m2'<- snd (damageMM (Just m1) (Just m2));
                     b' <- killMinion m1' b;
                     killMinion m2' b'}


killMinion :: Minion -> Board -> Board
killMinion m@(_,_,hp) b@(xs,ys) = if elem m xs && hp <= 0 then ((delete m xs),ys)
                                  else if elem m ys && hp <= 0 then (xs,(delete m ys))
                                  else b

damageMM :: Maybe Minion -> Maybe Minion -> Maybe (Minion,Minion)
damageMM Nothing _ = Nothing
damageMM _ Nothing = Nothing
damageMM (Just (n1,a1,hp1)) (Just (n2,a2,hp2)) = Just ((n1,a1,hp1-a2),(n2,a2,hp2-a1)) 

findMinion1 :: Name -> Board -> Maybe Minion
findMinion1 n ([],_) = Nothing
findMinion1 n ((x:xs),ys) = if n == fst3 x then Just x
                               else findMinion1 n (xs,ys) 


findMinion2 :: Name -> Board -> Maybe Minion
findMinion2 n (_,[]) = Nothing
findMinion2 n (xs,(y:ys)) = if n == fst3 y then Just y
                               else findMinion2 n (xs,ys) 


fst3 :: (a,b,c) -> a
fst3 (a,_,_) = a

trd3 :: (a,b,c) -> c
trd3 (_,_,c) = c
```

All the functions work as intended other than the attackMM function which causes many type mismatch errors. I've been staring at the code for a while and though I'm sure it's something obvious I could use a fresh pair of eyes to look at it. :)

Comment: To expand on @amalloy's comment in the answer, you should be using `let m1 = findMinion1 n b` instead of `m1 <- findMinion1 n b`.  The latter notation is for *monadic* binding, but this code is all "pure"

Comment: Although this is `Maybe` and not `IO`, I still think you would enjoy reading [The IO Monad for People who Simply Don't Care](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2007/11/io-monad-for-people-who-simply-dont.html) (and substituting `Maybe` for `IO` everywhere it's mentioned). It gives a few simple rules to follow when writing `do` blocks that will help you spot the errors you made here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `do` notation with the `Maybe` `Monad`.
So if you have something like `e <- f` inside your `do` block then `e :: a` and `f :: Maybe a`.

You use this correctly when you call `m1 <- findMinion1 n b;`.

But there is no need to wrap `m1` up in a `Just` again.

So change the type of `damageMM` to `Minion -> Minion -> Maybe (Minion,Minion)` and don't wrap them up in `Just`.

Then you'll have something like `m1'<- fst (damageMM m1 m2)` but this is still wrong because `damageMM m1 m2 :: Maybe (Minion,Minion)` and `fst :: (a,b) -> a`. The types don't match up. However `m1' :: (Minion,Minion)` so you want to call `fst` on that instead:

```
m1' <- fst (damageMM m1 m2);
let fm1' = fst m1'
```

Then you'll have `b' <- killMinion fm1' b` but `killMinion fm1' b :: Board`. You should be aware that `<-` is just nice syntax for using bind: `(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. In your `do` block, `m = Maybe`. In this instance, you use `<-` to "pull" values out of maybes, it is not for generally assigning variables to expressions. `let` is what you want for that:

```
let b' = killMinion m1' b
```

Finally, you want to return `killMinion m2' b'` as your final value. But you can't because you are returning from the `Maybe` `Monad` so you have to return a `Maybe`.

So you have to change the type signature: `attackMM :: Name -> Name -> Board -> Maybe Board` and put your return value back into a maybe: `return (killMinion m2' b')`.

Answer (score 0):

`findMinion1` returns a `Maybe Minion` and you are wrapping it with `Just m1`, then that type is a `Maybe (Maybe Minion)`, but `damageMM` expects a `Maybe Minion`.

Removing the `Just m1` (and `Just m2`) should work for the call to `damageMM` should work

Comment: I'd say a more pressing issue is that `attackMM` tries to use do-notation without being in any monad at all, and so all the `<-` bindings are errors.